# Access remote files Openshift

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I am new to openshift world. I have wordpress installed openshift application. I have configured and connected to application via putty ssh in windows. Now I don't know how to access files inside my app. Help me.

```
Welcome to OpenShift shell

This shell will assist you in managing OpenShift applications.

!!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!!
Shell access is quite powerful and it is possible for you to
accidentally damage your application.  Proceed with care!
If worse comes to worst, destroy your application with 'rhc app delete'
and recreate it
!!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!! IMPORTANT !!!

Type "help" for more info.

Note: Your application supports version 2 cartridges.

[xxxx-cloudrun.rhcloud.com xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]\>
```

Here I want know how to get access `xxxx/wp-content/`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 to bjwebb! Few links which could be of help to you.

Using FileZilla with OpenShift: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/access-files-with-filezilla

Using SFTP with OpenShift: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6G-Pkl_fzs

HTH

Comment: By not accepting his answer you deny him the credits

Answer (score 6):

Openshift applications are designed to be changed and deployed primarily using git, see https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications

Edit:
Creating the project should have given you a git url. Since you're using windows, you could use [tortoisegit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) to fetch this and make changes. wp-content is in the php directory of the git repository.

Alternatively:
The ssh login you have is a standard linux shell, you can add plugins/themes in the app-root/data directory, using standard linux shell tools.

```
[ ... ]\> cd app-root/data
[ ... data ]\> ls
blogs.dir  plugins  themes  uploads
```

You could even use a program like WinSCP to upload files to these directories using the SSH url you already have.

Comment: explain briefly please by example

Comment: Explanation added. It's hard to give an example, because there are several different git clients, and those for windows tend to be graphical.

Answer (score 0):

Use scp for linux or pscp for windows
Add the application to system path or use cd to go to that directory, then--

```
pscp -i pvtkey.ppk source destination
```

For example

```
pscp -i pvtkey.ppk my_file_to_upload xxxx-cloudrun.rhcloud.com:/the_path_to_upload_in_openshift_server
```

To upload a directory, use -r parameter

```
pscp -i pvtkey.ppk -r my_folder_to_upload xxxx-cloudrun.rhcloud.com:/the_path_to_upload_in_openshift_server
```

To Download, reverse the direction example

```
pscp -i pvtkey.ppk -r xxxx-cloudrun.rhcloud.com:/dir_to_download Path_of_my_pc
```

pvtkey.ppk is the private key in case of putty
 in linux, pvt key can be found on `~/.ssh`

To download a single file, remove -r paramater.

Link to download pscp http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe